# XNA - Accessing primary View, Project, World matrices from a game component

Tags: xna

In XNA4, I have an EnemyManager class that takes care of all of the enemies.  When it comes time to draw, however, it needs access to the game's main View, Projection, and World matrices.

I could just pass a reference to my DavesGame object down in there, but that seems like bad design.  I could put them in an interface and expose them as a game service.

I'm leaning towards the latter, but I'm wondering what the correct & elegant way to do it is.

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: Does your `EnemyManager` extend `GameComponent`?  I ask because `GameComponent` already has a property `Game` that points to the class instance that created it.  If not, you could collect your matrices in a `Camera` class and reference that.  Pretty normal practice there.

Comment: As Seth commented, just use a camera class and access the matrices from that.

Answer (score 2):

First let's assume how the matrices are "bundled" doesn't matter. I'd suggest a `Camera` class of some kind, but it doesn't matter - it could be a struct or as loose `Matrix` objects.

**Let's look at how you might pass that `Camera` around:**

Passing it around as a service isn't great. It's a lot of extra work and indirection, to fulfil a need that you probably don't have. Services are mostly for people making APIs that will be consumed by third-parties - and I assume you're not doing that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807121/165500) for a full description.

Grabbing it through `Game` is essentially no different to grabbing it through `Services`, but you lose all of the advantages (although you didn't need them anyway, and this saves you making a class).

You could be quick-and-dirty and make it "global" (in C# this would probably be a `public static` on your game class). This is ok when you want to do something [quickly](http://the-witness.net/news/2011/06/how-to-program-independent-games/). And in C# it's relatively painless to undo, once you need a "real" architecture.

Passing it into the constructor of your component isn't a great idea. Consider the very possible scenario where you'd like to draw your component twice. Perhaps for split-screen, perhaps for a level-editor. Then you very messily have to modify persistent state before each draw. If you can ignore this downside, it is a reasonable architecture.

But there's one more blindingly obvious option: **Why not just pass it in as a parameter to your `Draw` method?**

Oh, you can't because you're using `DrawableGameComponent`? The solution to that is simple: Stop using `DrawableGameComponent`! Seriously. It doesn't actually *add* anything to your architecture unless you're creating drag-and-drop-style components for third-party consumption (which, again, I am assuming you are not doing).

Its limitations are not worth the extra hoops you have to jump through, if you're not actually using it for its intended purpose.

I suggest you replace it with your own base class, where you can modify the method signatures on to your heart's content. The remaining infrastructure you get with `DGC` amounts to a list and a pair of loops, maybe 5 lines of trivial code.

I've written about why `DGC` is a terrible basis for an architecture (because it leaves you in these horrible tight spots) [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/288) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/16752/288) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725689/165500) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/40052/288).