# How to add several GameComponents of the same type?

Tags: xna, game-component

in order to load 3D-meshes to my project i created a BasicModel class. I made it a DrawableGameComponent so I can override methods like Draw & LoadContent. Plus I have access to the GraphicsDevice etc.

Now I realized that if I try to add several instances of the same GameComponent I get an exception that says that it is not allowed to do this.

1. Was it even a good thing to do, making the Class a GameComponent?
2. Is there a way to somehow differ single Components, so that I can add several copies of it to the game?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Was it even a good thing to do, making the Class a GameComponent?

No. You should only consider using `GameComponent`s for higher level concepts that sit directly on top of your `Game` class and will only require one instance to exist at any time.

Good examples are classes with *Manager* in their names such as a `ScreenManager`, `InputManager` or `AudioManager`, or classes that are built to be plug and play such as a `FramerateCounter` ([see link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924160406/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/06/08/displaying-the-framerate.aspx)) that you can easily reuse in any other project just by dropping it in.

So if for instance you created a scene graph class to store and manage the rendering and updating of your game world and all of its objects, you *might* consider making it a `DrawableGameComponent`. On the other hand, using it for each individual game object is not recommended at all.

Personally, I don't even use game components at all. I prefer having precise control over the updating and drawing of my classes, and if I need a reference to `Game` I can pass it on the constructor just as well without making the class a `GameComponent`. Don't let that discourage you from using them though, it's just a matter of personal preference, but just make sure you use them for the *right task*.

Comment: Do you think it somehow affects performance if I continue using that particular class?

Comment: @bodycountPP You wrote on your question that it doesn't let you add more than one `GameComponent` of the same type to the game component list (haven't verified this). How would you continue using it then? It's not even a matter of performance at this point - since it doesn't even work. My opinion is that you shouldn't even bother using them at all, and [others seem to think the same](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/11686).

Comment: @bodycountPP I've went ahead and checked it now, and indeed, the `GameComponentCollection` class doesn't let you add the same component multiple times. So, like I said, only use it for higher level concepts.

Comment: I am not really experienced but that would mean that I have to pass the graphicsdevice to every single instance of the BasicModel class. Is that a good programming style?

Comment: @bodycountPP Yes it's perfectly fine to make your BasicModel class require an instance of GraphicsDevice on its constructor.