# XNA GameServices vs. public static

Tags: xna, spritebatch

I am just starting learning XNA for developing Windows Phone games. I am stumbling accross different sample codes featuring different approaches on handling things.

A question for the experts... or at least for people who already have experiences with that topic:

Does it make more sense to inject instances of SpriteBatch via the constructor of game objects or adding the SpriteBatch object to the GameServices collection and retrieving it from the game objects' constructor like so:

```
spriteBatch = Game.Services.GetService(typeof(SpriteBatch)) as SpriteBatch;
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6807121/165500) and [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/288).

Answer (score 4):

**Use whatever feels more practical to you, and don't think too much about it.**

There's really no *best* answer to this, because there are so many different ways of doing it, but all of the possibilities work just as well. Personally I don't think it's worth bothering with `GameServices`, so I prefer either passing my dependencies or making them static public.

For `SpriteBatch` in particular, rather than passing it to the object's constructors, I prefer passing them only to my `Draw` methods instead. Or to be more specific, instead of passing `SpriteBatch` by itself, I create a class called `DrawContext` that contains a reference to the  `GraphicsDevice`, a `SpriteBatch`, a default `SpriteFont`, and provides a bunch of helper methods for doing things such as debug drawing of lines and text, and then pass that around to all `Draw` methods in my game.

But like I said, that's just personal preference. You can use `GameServices` if you want. You can create a public static reference to your `Game` instance and make the `SpriteBatch` public inside your game class, making it accessible anywhere on your application. You can pass the `SpriteBatch` to the constructor, or just the `Draw` method, or you can create a wrapper class for all graphic related objects like I did.

Since you know the alternatives, think which one you like better, and pick the one that seems less cumbersome to you.

*I* like the approach I described because I have a continuous chain of `Draw` calls starting on the `Game` and moving down the class hierarchy through the `ScreenManager`, the `Screen`s, the `Stage`, the `Layer`s, and finally to my individual `DisplayObject`s (nevermind those names, that's just the architecture I went with). And I know that within any `Draw` method I have everything I need contained in a single object. And if in the future I need a new feature, I just need to add it to that class (i.e. add to `DrawContext`).

But the biggest reason why I prefer passing my context around rather than using a public static reference to my `Game`, is because I happen to use the *same classes* for both my `Game`s and WinForms game editor which doesn't have a `Game` class. But like I said, that's just me, and my specific needs!

Comment: +1, that's exactly how I do, and it works very well for me.