# When to use GameComponents?

Tags: xna, c#, architecture, game-component

I know what it is and I'm using it as a frame counter for example. But when should I use it?

Does it make sense to say "I make all the input handling happen in a gamecomponent"? Is it flexible enough to add and remove fast in runtime? I see I can set the update order and draw order, but I guess to keep track of it an enum should be best like "GamePadInput = 0" or "MessageBox = 100".

Or should I just design simple, for example when I want to determinate if a messagebox is open checking "if (MessageBox.Active)" and then manually updating/drawing?

I'm a bit confused and can't decide what to do. I don't want to start designing the game and see later "oops". Maybe you can help me out :)

Comment: Dont be afraid to implement a _bad_ design first. Its better than falling into a design paralysis. Good designs are an evolution, implement something, see how it works, improve it if turns out bad. The more experience you get, the smaller the cycles will be, but there is no shortcut for that experience, you only get it from making mistakes, so "oops" is a good thing, just start with your idea.

Comment: IOW: Good judgement is obtained from the experience of exercising bad judgement.

Comment: Okay :) I think I'm going with the checking if something is active way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a big, somewhat controversial discussion [over here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/288) about why Game Components are "bad".

The most annoying thing about `GameComponent`, for me, is that it *looks* really important. It *looks* like a first-class part of the XNA API - like `Vector3` or `SoundEffect` - but they're actually not (everything in the `Game` assembly is technically optional).

So many an inexperienced developer (and a few intermediate ones who, frankly, have no taste) will come along thinking that implementing things with `GameComponent` is ***The Way*** to architect a game. It's not. And often they end up tying themselves up in knots to try and squash their code into a `GameComponent` shaped box.

So, to answer your question, **when *should* you use `GameComponent`?**

The "correct", "I am an experienced software engineer and know what I'm doing" answer is that you should probably only use `GameComponent` for its intended purpose: creating extremely loosely-coupled drag-and-drop style components to share between different games and different developers.

`GameComponent` (and its friend `DrawableGameComponent`) were designed to this exact thing. No more and no less.

Now, that being said, you can "fudge" this a little. If you wanted to explore the architectural possibilities, you could (as Maik in comments suggests) use `GameComponent` as some generic list for retaining game objects. However you will probably *very* quickly find that you have trouble with, for example, trying to get objects into your `Draw` or `Update` methods.

It is at this point that you should let go of `GameComponent` and take the few minutes to throw together your own actor/game-object/component base class and make a list of those. It really is a handful of lines of code.

(For some components you could just remove the base class completely and call `Draw` and `Update` directly. In fact, for some components - especially unique ones that have a fixed position in the draw/update order - this is often superior, as it removes a layer of indirection from your code.)

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459955/165500) on architecture.