# Monogame movement Handling

Tags: movement, monogame

I was curious if anyone could explain how I would be able to create simple movement handling in monogame. So far I have a red block which I tried to move by using a loop but that didn't take any effect.

```
protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            position = new Vector2(0, 0);
            texture = new Texture2D(this.GraphicsDevice, 100, 100);
            Color[] colorData = new Color[150 * 150];
            for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                colorData[i] = Color.Red;
            texture.SetData<Color>(colorData);
            base.Initialize();
        }
```

I also have created this handler but I don't exactly know what I have to do next.

```
/*protected override void HandleInput(KeyboardState keyState)
        {
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                // Look Up
            }
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            {
                // Look Down
            }
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                // Move Left
            }
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                // Move Right
            }
        }*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it is not clear if you use GameComponents or not, so I answer for both. I assume you do, since I think you are able to draw the Red Block and not update it. Which leads me to assume you haven't seen the `Update` and `Draw` methods in the main class.

Behavior and player input is handled in the *gameloop*. The gameloop is basically the "update the gameworld state"- "draw the gameworld state" cycle.

The *update* (like the *draw*) is handled in your main game class. Since you seem to be able to show the Red Block, you found the draw method.
In the main game class (`Game1`, if you follow the project template) you'll also find a pregenerated `Update` method:

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();
        }
```

From that method call your RedBlock object to do things. For example:

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

           KeyboardState kbstate = Keyboard.GetState();
           _myRedBlock.HandleInput(kbstate);
        }
```

This tells your Red Block code to execute the HandleInput every update frame.
From this you can update the `position.X` or `position.Y` based on the input.

You might have used a [GameComponent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx). When registered via `Game.Components.Add(_myRedBlock);`, the component automatically is updated and drawn in the gameloop. Use the `Update` in the GameComponent to have it updated each frame (see [GameComponent.Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.update.aspx)). From this Update, check the state of the keyboard and move the block accordingly.

Personally I don't use the GameComponent/DrawableGameComponent classes, but write my own game objects. There have been [debates](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56091/when-to-use-gamecomponents) on what architecture works best. Both ways work and each have their advantages.

Comment: Great! You can mark the answer as correct to close the question.

Comment: There! :) thx for helping out a newb