# Windows Phone XAML and XNA Apps with Game Components

Tags: xna-4.0, windows-phone-7

I am using the Windows Phone Template "Windows Phone XAML and XNA Apps" and targeting Windows Phone 7/8. Most examples show your game inheriting from `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` and then adding `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent` items to the `Components` collection. But as my game page inherits from `PhoneApplicationPage` there isn't a `Components` collection  or a `Game` property.

How can I use `GameComponent` from within `PhoneApplicationPage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Important parts of their infrastructure are contained within the `Game` class. (Also, `GameComponent`'s constructor takes a `Game`.)

My advice (as always) is to **not use `GameComponent`**. Like the `Game` class itself, game components are a completely optional part of the framework. And often they're [more trouble](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/9209/288) [than they're worth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12725689/165500).

You're better off [just](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221583.aspx) creating "normal" classes - however you like - and making a normal `List` to contain them. If you need any other functionality that the game component infrastructure provides, that's pretty simple to implement too.

For reference, that functionality basically amounts to: a mechanism for adding/removing/re-ordering items while the list is being iterated (as simple as copying the list before iterating), sorting components, disabling/hiding components, and calling the various [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent_methods(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) for you at the obvious times.

That being said, if you *really* want to use something identical to `GameComponent`, you could take the relevant code from [ExEn](http://exen.codeplex.com/) (or MonoGame, although I'm not sure what their code for this is like). The code in question is confined to [the GameComponents directory](http://exen.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#ExEnCommon/GameComponents/) and should be fairly independent. Unlike XNA itself, in ExEn the magic happens in the resuable `GameComponentCollection` class instead of deep inside the `Game` class.

(I looked into using XNA's own code for this - but it's not really possible to do in a way that isn't terrifying.)