# new graphicsdevice returning null

Tags: c#, monogame

I tried to make a collision box visible (for testing) with `spriteBatch.Draw`(with a blank texture) in my `TileSprite` class. I needed a `GraphicsDevice` for this so these are my variables:

```
Texture2D blankTexture;
GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice;
```

I used this code as my `LoadContent()`:

```
public void LoadContent()
{
    blankTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
    Color[] color = new Color[1];
    color[0] = Color.White;
    blankTexture.SetData(color);
}
```

I have one `TileSprite` constructor in my `TileSprite` class which looks like this (NOTE: this constructor is partially taken from another abstract class, named `Sprite`):

```
public TileSprite(GraphicsDevice gd, Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize, Point currentFrame)
    : base (gd, textureImage, position, frameSize, currentFrame)
{
    GraphicsDevice = gd;
    bCollisionRect = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, frameSize.X, frameSize.Y);
}
```

And then I use this code in my `Draw` method to draw the box:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(blankTexture, bCollisionRect, Color.White);
```

And I have another line of code in the `Game1 : Game` class (variables like `textureImage` are written as variables in the beginning of the `Game1` class):

```
tileSprite = new TileSprite(this.GraphicsDevice, textureImage, position, frameSize, currentFrame);
```

I tested this and I saw that my `GraphicsDevice` was returning `null` on a `new TileSprite` that used a GraphicsDevice from `DrawableGameComponent`.

Comment: OK, are you saying that TileSprite is a DrawableGameComponent?  Honestly, you shouldn't be using DrawableGameComponents, they are really poorly designed.

Comment: What should I use then? I followed a couple of monogame tutorials and they made a sort of little project and I worked further on it. So all my methods in the `SpriteManager : DrawableGameComponent` class are from `DrawableGameComponent`

Comment: DrawableGameComponent was supposed to be more fleshed out, by was pretty much abandoned by XNA after 1.0.  Read more about it here:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/what-are-the-cons-of-using-drawablegamecomponent-for-every-instance-of-a-game-ob

Comment: Thank you for the link! But do you know why `GraphicsDevice` is returning `null`?

Comment: I would need to see more code, specifically how you are initializing the SpriteManager.  I would personally seriously remove the DrawableGameComponent stuff.

Comment: But what do I replace `DrawableGameComponent` with? Do I just make custom Initialize, Draw, Update, .... methods? And I use `base.Initialize();` in my initialize method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31268/discussion-between-jelle-and-jon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you would use the GraphicsDevice object that is created in your Game class.  You should be able to create a second Graphics Device, however, I think there is a access issue when you attempt to create a second GraphicsDevice using the same adapter.

> When you create a new XNA Framework game using XNA Game Studio
>   Express, the game derives from Game and contains a member variable
>   that is a GraphicsDeviceManager. This GraphicsDeviceManager
>   automatically creates the best device that is available for the
>   application and exposes it as the GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice
>   property.

So what you are going to want to do, is pass the Game.GraphicsDevice object to this class in order to use the same one that is already initialized.

**As requested in comments, an example:**

```
public class TileSprite
{
    GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice;
    Texture2D BlankTexture;

    public TileSprite(GraphicsDevice gd)
    {
        GraphicsDevice = gd;
    }

    public void LoadContent()
    {       
        BlankTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        Color[] color = new Color[1];
        color[0] = Color.White;
        BlankTexture.SetData(color);        
    } 
}
```

Then in your Game class:

```
TileSprite tileSprite = new TileSprite(this.GraphicsDevice);
```

Comment: Thanks. You are really helpfull! But one question though. I'm new to programming and how do I pass the `GraphicsDevice` to the `TileSprite` class?

Comment: You could add a variable to your TileSprite constructor of type GraphicsDevice, and then pass it along that way.

Comment: Could you give me a little example? I already have a variable of type `GraphicsDevice` in my class constructor, but I'm still a little bit confused on how to pass it.

Comment: @Jelle I added a small code example, as requested.

Comment: I implemented your code and I can run my program. I tested if `GraphicsDevice` was `null` and it wasn't. But when I wanted to draw my boxes (my previous question), then I get a NullException (probably from my GraphicsDevice). I will update my question above.

Comment: I changed my `SpriteManager` class and I found something odd. It's not my `GraphicsDevice` that was returning null, but it's the `Color[] color`....